# Connect from uMongo to EC2

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to remotely connect to MongoDB on an Amazon EC2 server using uMongo.

I've opened a port on my Amazon server:

- Type: Custom TCP Rule
- Protocol: TCP
- Port Range: 27017
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0.

I've added a connection in uMongo with the following settings:

- Name: Porject Name
- Servers: https://12.34.56.789:27017
- Connection Mode: Automatic
- Socket Type: Plain
- Connect Timeout: 2,000
- Socket Timeout: 0
- Safe Writes: [checked]
- Proxy Type: None
- Proxy Host: localhost
- Proxy Port: 9,000

All the other fields are empty. Basically, I only changed the "Servers" field and left all the others untouched.

Then, when I try to connect via this connection, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//12.34.56.789"
>     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)   at
>   com.edgytech.umongo.MainMenu.connect(MainMenu.java:177)   at
>   com.edgytech.umongo.MainMenu.connect(MainMenu.java:118)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.edgytech.swingfast.ButtonBase.actionPerformed(ButtonBase.java:297)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)  at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, do a simple telnet diagnosis  from your remote site to the mongodb : 
`telnet 12.34.56.789  27017` . If the connection rejected, you need to fix the security group. Please refer to AWS mongodb documentation about remote connection setup.

Comment: @mootmoot the telnet test has passed successfully. It must be something basic that I miss. I've never remotely connected to MongoDB. Any other thing you can think about?

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException` means you are passing unrecognised value. Please check umongo documentation whether  `server` field accept url schema such as `http` or `https`. Try use IP address/fqdn for server name.

Comment: @mootmoot yes! You are a genius! I've changed it to use an IP address and it works now! Please rewrite it as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you encounter java.lang.NumberFormatException, it means it doesn't recognize the number format. i.e.

```
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//12.34.56.789"
```

In such case, the server name parser try its best effort to deal with both FQDN and IP address. In such case, the parser strip the url scheme (http/https/ftp,etc) and assume you enter IP address. It invoke try to parse number, but failed, because the prefix"//".

To fix this, please enter either IP address or fully qualified domain name (FQDN) without url scheme

Answer (score 0):

based on the error message, it looks like you've configured the 'connection' wrong by including 'https' in the host string. try just '12.34.56.789:27017' instead and like another poster above mentioned, first check that you can even connect to the mongo host using something like:

```
telnet 12.34.56.789 27017
```

if your EC2 security group is set up wrong, the telnet command will just hang indefinitely, saying 'Trying 12.34.56.78...'

HTH